# multiple concatenation chars in c++

Tags: c++, char, expression, concatenation, literals

I have a very simple question.
How could I concatenate multiple chars in C++? For example I would like to make expressions like these valid:

Call_Function('a' + 'b' + 'c' + 'd');
Expected Result: "abcd";

Call_Function("a" + 'b' + "c");
Expected Result: "abc";

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It must be said that the Expected result can be std::string too and not only a const char *. On the other side the expression of the called functions is expected to be written exactly like it is i.e. no cast is allowed. Is it possible in C++?

Comment: Is it literal char, or do they come from variable ?

Comment: It can be a mix of both. You could have for example: char x; Call_Function("a" + x + "b"); or Call_Function('a' + x + 'b');

Answer (score 0):

For concatenation of string literals, you may let the preprocessor do the job

`"hello" " world"` results in `"hello world"`.

with variables, the simpler is to use `std::string` and `operator +`

```
std::string s;
```

`s + "Hello" + ' ' + "world"` would result in `std::string("Hello world")`

In c++14, it can be shorten with

```
using namespace std::string_literals; // for operator ""s
"Hello"s + ' ' + world
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but could I overload the operator+ or create any other construction so that the argument expressions can be written exactly like in the example?

Comment: Exactly not, as `char + char` or `char* + int` has already a meaning. but c++14 introduce shortcut to create `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks! do you refer to operator""s or what exactly do you mean by new C++14 shortcut?

Comment: Yes, I meant `operator""s` for the C++14 *shortcut*: `"Hello"s`